# why doesn't the sidebar get updated in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had to maunally add some html within the sidebar div of html, but I when I preview/activate this theme, it doesnt show the maunal updated content of sidebar, do I need to add this to sidebar.php also and if so where. I am a total nood to both wp as well as php.  Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the recommended way for Wordpress sidebar (sidebar.php)

```
<ul id="sidebar">
   <?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
       <li>{static sidebar item 1}</li>
       <li>{static sidebar item 2}</li>
   <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

but if you always want to have some static items on your sidebar then you can make sidebar.php as follows

```
// Static items will be always at the top of the sidebar
<ul id="sidebar">
    <?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
        <li>{static sidebar item 1}</li>
        <li>{static sidebar item 2}</li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>

if(function_exists(‘dynamic_sidebar’) && dynamic_sidebar()) :

endif;
```

**Reference : [Register Sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) and [Dynamic Sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar).**

**This is your current sidebar (not dynamic)**

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/searchform.php'); ?> 
<div id="sidebar"> 
    <h3>Category</h3>
    <ul class="ul-cat"> 
        <?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li='); ?> 
    </ul>
    <h3>Archives</h3>
    <ul class="ul-archives"> 
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But this I can just add in using manual html copy and paste to sidebar.php. how does it make a difference

Comment: This is a dynamic sidebar, anyway, Can you tell me what do you want add in your sidebar ?

Comment: Your sidebar is not dynamic and contains only three things, search form, category list and archive list.

Comment: i need some ul li like items, exam venues, talk dates, project deadlines and about me in the sidebar

Comment: Then add those static items before/after `if(function_exists(‘dynamic_sidebar’) && dynamic_sidebar()) : endif;`

Comment: Follow references given in my answer.

Comment: how do i get li's actually, ca you plz give syntax
<ul id="sidebar">
    <?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
        <li>{static sidebar item 1}</li>
        <li>{static sidebar item 2}</li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>

Comment: Put your link/a tags inside li like `<li><a href="">Menu Item</a></li>`

Comment: h3 also becomes an li tag here, how do I avoid that

Comment: Don't put h3 tags inside li tags.

Comment: My h3 isnt inside li tags, actually something is not proper in php code

Comment: I'm not sure what you are taking about, can you show your code ?

Comment: This is at the bottom of my sidebar.php:
<?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar() ) : else : ?>
  
   <ul class="ul-cat"> 
        <?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li='); ?> 
   
    </ul>
 
 <ul class="ul-cat">
  <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?> 
</ul>  
  <?php endif; ?>
   
  and when I see this in firebug, i see li's without enclsing ul e-g
<li class="widget widget_categories" id="categories-8"><h2 class="widgettitle">Categories</h2>
  <ul>
 <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a title="View all posts filed under Unca......
</li>
  </ul>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing your browser cache? And are you sure you're not caching your pages using a plugin or if the hosting is caching the content?

Comment: cache is not the issue, but I just look at my sidebar.php and it has only this piece
 <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/searchform.php'); ?>
 
 <div id="sidebar">
  <h3>Category</h3>
  <ul class="ul-cat">
   <?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li='); ?>
  </ul>
  <h3>Archives</h3>
  <ul class="ul-archives">
   <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <!--/sidebar -->
I doubt if that is incomplete and maybe customized only for the theme I am using, Is there a default code for sidebar which caters to whole